# Reservation system - checking if the date is free [Laravel 8]

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to check if the date range is free.

This is the structure of my tables:

```
Reservations 

id            int(10)   
procuct_id    int(10)   
start         (date)
end           (date)
```

.

```
Products

id           int(10)    
name         varchar(600)
```

I did something like this:

```
return Reservations::where('procuct_id', $product_id)->where(function ($query) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
            $query->where(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('start_date', '>=', $start_date)
                    ->where('start_date', '=<', $start_date);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('end_date', '>=', $start_date)
                    ->where('end_date', '<=', $start_date);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('start_date', '>=', $end_date)
                    ->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('end_date', '>=', $end_date)
                    ->where('end_date', '<=', $end_date);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('start_date', '<=', $start_date)
                    ->where('end_date', '>=', $start_date);
            })->orWhere(function ($q) use ($start_date, $end_date) {
                $q->where('start_date', '<=', $end_date)
                    ->where('end_date', '>=', $end_date);
            });
        })->count();
```

This does not work when the second booking begins on the day the other booking ends.

For example:

Database dates:

```
Start 01-01-2021   End 04-01-2021
```

I want to make a new date booking

```
Start 04-01-2021   End 08-01-2021
```

Unfortunately, this query shows me that this date is already booked (and it is not).

Comment: Be aware of ending date with hour set to `00:00` if you check `<= 'end_date'` It will never be this case. For ending date, change it with `23:59`

Comment: @FrédéricKlee column type is date not datetime